# How to convert COBOL COMP, COMP-1 and COMP-2 into Java Long or Int

Tags: java, hadoop, ftp, cobol

I am working to Mainframe to Hadoop migration and have very knowledge in Java.
I have a cobol flat file which contains computational fields (COMP, COMP-1, COMP-2). I have to use this file in Java application.

Need help to understand below points:

1. **How to FTP mainframe flat file which has COMP fields.** I tried to FTP it but got non readable characters. **I tried to FTP in Binary Mode but still its not readable.**
2. **How to convert Cobol COMP fields in to JAVA int/long.** If you have any sample java snippet. Please share.

I have found java snippet for COMP-3 to Java Long on below link:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/411222/java/java/Packed-decimal-conversion-Java

Appreciate you help.

Comment: COMP is a binary field, which will be two, four or eight bytes long depending on the PICture. COMP-1/COMP-2 are floating-point of four and eight bytes respectively. Be very careful to confirm that *your* floating-point is the same as IBM's floating-point. All these fields must be transferred as BINARY. However, any text fields in the same file will suffer if that is done. Sensible thing is never to transfer internal data-types across systems, but to convert them to "text" on the source system. Or look at other questions tagged java and COBOL.

Comment: I can't believe the conversation and code in the link you gave for the comp-3. Convert it on the Mainframe (standard code, SORT or COBOL) and 0 lines of Java, or all that rubbish for each field (remembering even that is source code, not the stuff which executes) and it is not even definitive. Jeez.

Comment: As Bill said Convert on the mainframe. Comp-1 and Comp-2 are completely different from Comp-3. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture for a description of Mainframe floating point.

Comment: If you transfer the file as Binary, you should be able to read and process as a byte stream. You will need to work out where records start and end. As you have comp-1/comp-2 this would be a waste of time. Translate to Text on the Mainframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the parser behind [Cobrix](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/cobrix). This is an open-source COBOL data source for Spark and it copes with COMP fields.